# Plotting sea areas using osmplotr and OpenStreetmap in R

Tags: r, gis, openstreetmap

I am trying to use Openstreetmap, via the `osmplotr` package on CRAN, to draw a coastline and color the sea blue. Because the sea is not a polygon, I tried to use `osm_line2poly()` to turn the lines into a polygon. However, the minimum reproducible example below gives the following error:

```
Error in osm_line2poly(bar, bbox = mybbox) : 
  obj must be class 'sf' with fields of class 'sfc_LINESTRING'
```

It seems to be saying that the object is of the incorrect type, but if I do a `class(bar)` it results in:

```
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

So the class looks as if it is indeed `sf`. I would be glad for any pointers.

Code follows.

```
require(OpenStreetMap)
require(osmplotr)
require(osmdata)

# Define the bounding box
mybbox <- get_bbox (c(-4.9339, 52.0602, -4.7422, 51.9654))
# Get the coastline
dat_Z <- extract_osm_objects (key = 'natural', value = 'coastline', bbox = mybbox)
# Define the base map and its color
map <- osm_basemap (bbox = mybbox, bg = 'white')
# Add the coastline to the map
map <- add_osm_objects (map, dat_Z, col = 'gray40')
# And plot
print_osm_map (map)
# We want to color the sea (in the top-left quadrant) blue. In the docs:
# https://ropensci.github.io/osmplotr/reference/osm_line2poly.html
# ...it says 
# "Converts sf::sfc_LINSTRING objects to polygons by connecting end points 
# around the given bounding box. This is particularly useful for plotting water 
# and land delineated by coastlines. Coastlines in OpenStreetMap are lines, not
# polygons, and so there is no directly way to plot ocean water distinct from
# land. This function enables that by connecting the end points of coastline 
# LINESTRING objects to form closed polygons."

bar <- extract_osm_objects(mybbox, key = 'natural', value = 'coastline', 
                           return_type = 'polygon', sf = TRUE, geom_only = FALSE)

foo <- osm_line2poly(bar, bbox = mybbox)
```

Output:
[image: coastline using osmplotr]

Comment: The problem is that the `osm_line2poly` function expects a sf object whose geometry type is LINESTRING while the geometry type of the object `bar` is POLYGON (since you set `return_type = polygon` and you can see that printing the bar object after loading the sf package). If you read the examples in the documentation of the `osm_line2poly` function, you can see that the authors set the parameter return_type equal to "line" so that the geometry type of the result is LINESTRING.

Comment: Anyway I think that there are some problems with the `osm_line2poly` function since if I run the examples in the documentation I get the following warning: Warning message: In osm_line2poly(coast, bbox = bb) : No open curves found - check for polygons. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Thanks, setting `return_type = linestring` fixes the previous issue, but the code now throws `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (V = m2)`, which is tangentially mentioned in https://github.com/ropensci/osmplotr/issues/29. That issue is still open, so I guess it was never fixed and that the `osm_line2poly` function is, for now, not working.

Comment: This is actually a really difficult problem, hence no real solution yet. In the meantime, you could check out [this pull request](https://github.com/ropensci/osmplotr/pull/38/files) which illustrates one attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Until the authors of the package fix the issues with `osm_line2poly` I think you could use the following code to plot the sea area. It's not really a solution to your problems since it uses a different approach to plot the sea area but maybe it's good enough.

```r
# packages
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

# download from OSM coastline line for your bounding box
coastline_data <- opq(c(-4.9339, 52.0602, -4.7422, 51.9654)) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = 'natural', value = 'coastline') %>% 
  osmdata_sf()

# create the LINESTRING sf (i.e. the coastline) and the POLYGONS sf (i.e. the
# islands)
coastline <- coastline_data$osm_lines
islands <- coastline_data$osm_polygons

# download from OSM the tiles/raster data of the bounding box where the
# coastlines are
background_data <- read_osm(sf::st_bbox(coastline))

# plot
tm_shape(background_data) + 
  tm_rgb() + 
tm_shape(coastline_data$osm_lines) + 
  tm_lines() + 
tm_shape(coastline_data$osm_polygons) + 
  tm_polygons() + 
  tm_scale_bar() + 
  tm_compass(type = "8star", position = c("left", "top"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? I just learned how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829258/plot-filled-areas-for-sea-ocean-and-land-mass-based-on-osmdata-using-ggplot2).

```r
library(lwgeom)
library(osmdata)
library(osmplotr)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

### define example bbox
lon_min <- -4.9339 # xmin
lon_max <- -4.7422 # xmax
lat_min <- 51.9654 # ymin
lat_max <- 52.0602 # ymax

bb <- get_bbox(c(lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max))

### get sea & land as polygons
# 1. get coastline (as line)
coast <- opq(bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "coastline") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

# 2. get overall rectangle for bbox
bb_rect <- data.frame(
  lat = c(lat_min, lat_max),
  lon = c(lon_min, lon_max)
) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

# 3. split overall rectangle for bbox via coastline
bb_rect_split <- bb_rect %>% 
  st_split(coast$osm_lines) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

# 4. extract splitted rectangle parts
land <- bb_rect_split[1]
sea  <- bb_rect_split[2]

### ggplot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = land,
    fill = "bisque",
    color = NA
  ) + 
  geom_sf(
    data = sea,
    fill = "navy",
    color = NA
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>