# Plot filled areas for sea/ocean and land mass based on {osmdata} using {ggplot2}

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, openstreetmap, r-sf

The reprex below shows how I would like to create a map via {osmdata} and {ggplot2} that has sea/ocean in it. I want to color-fill the land and/or sea area. However, it seems unexpectedly difficult to do so. [This blog post](https://jacintak.github.io/post/2021-07-01-OSM-in-R/#:%7E:text=Sadly%20the%20ocean%20cannot%20be%20mapped.) even claims that it cannot be done.

This [vignette of {osmplotr}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmplotr/vignettes/maps-with-ocean.html#:%7E:text=The%20osm_line2poly()%20function%20can%20then%20converte%20these%20lines%20to%20polygons%20which%20can%20be%20used%20to%20plot%20filled%20areas.) seems to have to the solution: *"Because OpenStreetMap represents coastline as line objects, all coastline data is contained within the `$osm_lines` object. The `osm_line2poly()` function can then convert these lines to polygons which can be used to plot filled areas.*". Yet, just as in [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124407/plotting-sea-areas-using-osmplotr-and-openstreetmap-in-r), the function throws an error as can be seen at the bottom of the reprex. I also found [here](http://estebanmoro.org/post/2020-10-19-personal-art-map-with-r/#:%7E:text=The%20US%20Census%20has%20an%20amazing%20service%20called%20Tiger%20to%20retrieve%20those%20boundaries%20in%20ESRI%E2%80%99s%20shapefile%20format.%20In%20R%2C%20we%20can%20access%20those%20shapefiles%20using%20the%20tigris%20package.) that the {tigris} package can provide the necessary polygon data - but only for the US.

So how can I get this to work?

```r
library(osmdata)
library(osmplotr)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# define example bbox
bb <- tribble(
  ~xy,  ~min,  ~max,
  "x", 12.00, 12.18,
  "y", 54.08, 54.20
) %>% column_to_rownames("xy") %>% as.matrix()

# get "water"
water <- opq(bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "water") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

# get "coastline"
coast <- opq(bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "coastline") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

# ggplot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = water$osm_multipolygons,
    fill = "navy",
    color = NA
  ) + 
  geom_sf(
    data = coast$osm_lines,
    fill = "navy",
    color = "blue"
  )
```

[image]

```r
# trying osm_line2poly()
osmplotr::osm_line2poly(coast$osm_lines, bb)
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): unbenutztes Argument (V = c(3, 1, 6, 7, 2, NA, 5))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: When you have the coast as a line you can intersect it with your bounding box - creating a polygon - consider the earlier answer I just linked

Comment: Use Jindra's suggestion :). Otherwise you may consider looking for all water dataset: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I did use Jindra's suggestion. However, when investigating your alternative, I immediately wondered how to efficiently import/deal with this huge dataset of all water polygons in the world. It seems a bit overkill or am I missing an approach that focuses on my bbox from the start and thus is fast?

Comment: @PaulSchmidt, you can query the layer during `st_read()` with `query = ` parameter, like `sf::st_read(water, query = "SELECT * FROM water_polygons WHERE X between 12.0 AND 13 AND Y between 54 AND 55")`. But don't focus to much on it, I like the solution you provided. Just remember, that sometimes `osmdata` queries returns a bit more than requested bbox, therefore sometimes it's needed to `st_crop()` the data to the bbox of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@JindraLacko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829258/plot-filled-areas-for-sea-ocean-and-land-mass-based-on-osmdata-using-ggplot2#comment130366544_73829258), I was able to make my reprex work. Basically, we create a rectangle/polygon which is the size of our bbox and then split it via the coastline.

```r
library(lwgeom)
library(osmdata)
library(osmplotr)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

### define example bbox
lon_min <- 12.00 # xmin
lon_max <- 12.18 # xmax
lat_min <- 54.08 # ymin
lat_max <- 54.20 # ymax

bb <- get_bbox(c(lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max))

### get "water" that is not sea as polygons
water <- opq(bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "water") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

### get sea & land as polygons
# 1. get coastline (as line)
coast <- opq(bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "coastline") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

# 2. get overall rectangle for bbox
bb_rect <- data.frame(
  lat = c(lat_min, lat_max),
  lon = c(lon_min, lon_max)
) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

# 3. split overall rectangle for bbox via coastline
bb_rect_split <- bb_rect %>% 
  st_split(coast$osm_lines) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

# 4. extract splitted rectangle parts
land <- bb_rect_split[1]
sea  <- bb_rect_split[2]

### ggplot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = land,
    fill = "bisque",
    color = NA
  ) + 
  geom_sf(
    data = sea,
    fill = "navy",
    color = NA
  ) + 
  geom_sf(
    data = water$osm_multipolygons,
    fill = "navy",
    color = NA
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>