# Mapping without maritime boundaries OSM data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I'm trying to do a map without maritime boundaries or, ideally, `steelblue` between the maritime borders and the coastline. This is my code:

```
all_boundaries <- opq(bbox = c(-117.823506, 27.742140, -112.517109, 32.712813)) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary",
                  value = c("administrative")) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "4") %>%  # Administrative level for states
   osmdata_sf()

usmex <- opq(bbox = c(-117.823506, 27.742140, -112.517109, 32.712813)) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary",
                  value = c("administrative")) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "2") %>%  # Administrative level for states
  osmdata_sf()

coast <- opq(bbox = c(-117.883506,27.742140,-112.517109,33.961826)) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "coastline") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = all_boundaries$osm_multipolygons,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "lightgrey",
          size = .7,
          alpha = .8) + 
  geom_sf(data = coast$osm_lines,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "steelblue",
          size = .7,
          alpha = .8) +
  geom_sf(data = usmex$osm_lines,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "red",
          size = .7,
          alpha = .8) +
  geom_sf(data = coast$osm_polygons,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "steelblue",
          size = 12,
          alpha = .8)+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-112.517109,-117.823506), 
           ylim = c(27.742140,33.961826),
           expand = FALSE)+
  geom_point( aes(x=-116.8476211, y=31.9885162), size = .9, alpha=.8, fill="firebrick4", color="white", pch=21, inherit.aes = F) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  geom_point( aes(x=-116.8476211, y=31.9885162), size = .9, alpha=.8, fill="firebrick4", color="white", pch=21, inherit.aes = F) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, family = "lato", face="bold", hjust=.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "lato", size = 12, hjust=.5, margin=margin(2, 0, 5, 0)))
```

I want the border between countries very distinctively, that's why I'm using `admin_level=2` and `4`. At first, I tried to distinguish the sea using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829258/plot-filled-areas-for-sea-ocean-and-land-mass-based-on-osmdata-using-ggplot2) but it didn't work.

So how can I get my map without maritime borders but clear country borders `admin_level=2`?